# Is it correct to say "We will let you know when this option will be available"

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence correct?

> We will let you know when this option will be available.

Since this option is not available yet. 
It will be available soon.

So, is it correct to say:

> We will let you know when this option will be available.

or

> We will let you know when this option be available.

Comment: We will let you know when this option is available

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  April Fools.

Answer (score 9):

**Choice 1:**

> We will let you know when this option *will be* available.

Yes, **it is a grammatically correct sentence**.

Use the above sentence if your intention is that, at some point in the future, you will let the readers know the exact date the option *will be* available, (meaning the actual date of availability for that option is even further in the future).

A slightly modified alternative is to say:

> We will let you know when this option *will become* available.

---

**Choice 2:**

> We will let you know when this option *is* available.

Use this choice if, at a future date, you will let them know the option *is* available. In other words, when the option has become available, you will let them know at that time.

---

**Choice 3:**

> We will let you know when this option *be* available.

This is grammatically incorrect. **Do NOT use Choice 3**.

Here's a usable alternative to Choice 3:

> We will let you know when this option *becomes* available.

Comment: I don't see much difference between Choice 1 and Choice 2, except for a repetition of the same auxiliary verb in the former. I think the first instance of auxiliary 'will' does the job of ensuring that the option will be available on a future date, so I don't see any reason to repeat it in the next clause. As much as anything, Choice 1 makes for unconventional sentence-structure and I for one would certainly avoid such usage. Moreover I'm sceptical as to its acceptability in the realm of grammar.

Comment: @AndySemyonov, even with my explanation you don't notice the difference between Choices 1 and 2? I do agree with you that Choice 2 sounds better, because Choice 1 sounds a bit redundant. But there is a slight technical difference.

Comment: No I don't, I'm adamant Choice 1 and Choice 2 mean the same thing, the former however seems to be bad English style.

Comment: @AndySemyonov, if you don't currently know the date the option will be available, but you will let users know the date it should become available when you figure out that date...what would you say?

Comment: "When the option becomes available"...

Comment: @AndySemyonov, I mean, how would you tell them you will provide an estimated availability date for the option at some point in the future?

Comment: When the option has become available?, I would even suggest a possible time span if it's necessary, like when option has become available in next 2-3 months. My examples are making perfect sense and sound good to an English ear but for the life of me, I can't agree that Choice 1 sounds normal to any native speaker.

Comment: @AndySemyonov, but you aren't letting them know when the option *becomes* available. You're letting them know when it *will become* available. If I say "I'll call you when I know your tuxedo is ready", that means at the point that I call you your tuxedo is ready. If, instead, I say "I'll call you when I know when your tuxedo will be ready", that means at the point that I call you your tuxedo isn't ready, but I can let you know the exact date it will be ready; on that exact date, it *has become* ready.

Comment: As I said earlier, it just doesn't sound normal or is certainly bad-style. I know I'd prefer saying, we'll win if we play well as opposed to we'll win if we'll play well. The tense is in future in the main clause and the subordinating clause should be understood in the same manner, there is no need to insert a duplicate auxiliary verb in trying to make the sentence ultra-comprehensive. Bad-style to use the same auxiliary verb twice, I repeat.

Comment: @AndySemyonov, but your example doesn't add any additional information by using "will" again. You can see from the tuxedo example, there is additional information passed on by the use of an additional "will [be]". To put that example in a more natural form, someone would probably say: "I'll call you when I know the date your tuxedo will be ready". I tried to replicate features of the OPs posted sentence in my original tuxedo example, but perhaps that made my point unclear. However, you can see that my modified tuxedo example in this comment sounds natural, despite repeating "will [be]".

Comment: @AndySemyonov, with that said, it is more likely that the OP intended to convey Choice 2. But, Choice 1 is still a legitimate choice for the specific situation I outlined.

Comment: I can't agree on that. You weren't to specify the 'date' in your tuxedo eg. or going by OP's query. "I'll call you when I know your tuxedo will be ready," should have been the sentence, but you see it doesn't sound good. I'd prefer the first version of it i.e with tuxedo is ready.

Comment: Our disagreement comes down to the taste of style, I think,and it's an enviable trait to incline always to the taste that is natural, acceptable and uncomplicated, by that I don't mean your sentence is complicated, but it's in a bad-style.

Comment: @AndySemyonov, you seem to miss the fact that it has a different meaning.

Comment: @AndySemyonov It’s not a matter of style or taste. The two versions have different meanings. Or rather, version 2 can in certain contexts (but not all) convey _both_ meanings, whereas version 1 can only convey one of the meanings. “I’ll let you know tomorrow when I’m there” means specifically that I will be there tomorrow; “I’ll let you know tomorrow when I’ll be there” means that I will be there at some point _after_ the time when I talk to you tomorrow—it could be that I won’t be there for another week. The sentences have completely different syntactic structures: in version 1, [cont’d-->]

Comment: Or you could say, you'll let them know tomorrow when you can be there to make better sense and convey only one definite meaning.

Comment: [-->cont’d] the prepositional phrase is the object of the verb _know_, and as such it must appear in the object slot after the verb and can be replaced by a pronoun like _it_: “I’ll let you know _it_”. In version 2, it is an temporal-adverbial phrase that can be moved around freely and replaced by an adverb like _then_: “When I’m there tomorrow, I’ll let you know” / “I’ll let you know _then_”. Both versions are perfectly correct, both grammatically and stylistically, but they mean fundamentally different things.

Comment: @AndySemyonov That is yet another meaning. “I will be there at five” is not the same as “I can be there at five”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, any suggested edits so I can more clearly explain the difference? I try to make my explanations simple enough so non-native speakers can easily understand, but apparently I wasn't clear enough here.

Comment: Of course it isn't. But what you meant to imply by saying, "you'll let know when you'll know" can be better implied by "you'll let know, when you do know definitely."

Comment: I'm one for avoiding the same auxiliary in the main and subordinating clause. Almost a rule of thumb for me.

Comment: Mike: I think perhaps the substitution test (replacing the phrase with a pronoun or adverb, as relevant) is the clearest way of getting the structural difference of the two sentences to click into place. @AndySemyonov Yes, because the semantics of that sentence makes it quite unlikely that the ‘future-future’ (as it were) is intended. And in that case, version 2 _can_ express both meanings. But in some contexts, like the one I mentioned above, that just isn’t possible.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, so only with the addition of examples can it be clearer? I was trying to avoid cluttering it up with more blockquotes and lines, honestly. I thought perhaps my sentences could be more articulate.

Comment: You could also add what questions they answer: version 1 answers “What will you let me know?”, while version 2 answers “When will you let me know?”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, nice idea.

Comment: I was able to make some different sense out of @JanusBahsJacquet's "I'll let you know" eg. I think the obvious difference was that in the 1st eg the 1st person is proposing to let the 2nd person know "when/at what time" they'll be at a particular place. However, in the 2nd eg. they're proposing to "say something" when they get to a particular place. I wasn't able to make any sense out of the OP'S intent to say the same thing in 2 different manners. 
Furthermore, I'd prefer a rather simplified and definite structure for your 2 sentences too. Since in your 2nd eg. your intent is to say <cont.>

Comment: something upon arrival, why not opt to mention that? You  could say : 
I'll let you know that, when/whenever I'm there. 
Your intent is in saying something secretive and not in mentioning the time/date of the arrival, and even if such is the case, a voracious reader such as myself would construe that from the main clause's auxiliary verb.

Comment: A better case of it was made in some other post by a different user - option is available' which is a static thing in present while 'will let you know' is a future tense , when first sentence is in future tense second should be in present as a supportive sentence e.g: 'I will let you know which is best' – Hemali Luhar.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, for the life of me, I can't come up with questions to differentiate the Choices without sounding redundant to the Choices themselves.

Comment: @Mike I'll be there to argue, even if you do come up with such sentences. They're out of sense for me. :)

Comment: @AndyT, thanks for your thoughts. Would you mind submitting an edit? My main concern is preventing the answer from looking too cluttered. So if you can figure out a way to cleanly format with your suggestion included, that would be great!

Comment: @AndyT, his example question just seems to be redundant to the actual response. I nearly put the same thing in my answer, but concluded it didn't really add value since it was tautological.

Comment: @AndyT, what do you think now? Still seems a bit wordy to me though (which is definitely my fault for making it wordier, of course).

Comment: Oh gosh! This edit is ridiculous, I think you guys are trying every possible way to make the sentence look as it doesn't naturally appear to the reader. Where in the 1st sentence it says "the availability of the option is even further in the future?" You can't give such an erroneous explanation that no reader in their right minds would decipher from that sentence.

Comment: Calling me an idiot and then giving me an explanation to your point? I have no interest in listening to a capricious mind.

Answer (score 1):

**Scenario 1:**

Customer : I heard that Option A will be available soon. Could you look into your database and let me know when it will be available ?

Agent : Sure, my assistant here will access the database records. **We will let you know when this option will be available.**

Assistant (few seconds later) : It will be available starting on Friday.

**Scenario 2:**

Customer : I want to buy that Device as soon as Option A becomes available. Here is my contact number. Can you let me know when it becomes available ?

Agent : Sure, my assistant here will take your number. **We will let you know when this option becomes available.**

Assistant (few months later) : You wanted to know when Option A becomes available. We are happy to inform you that it is available now.

---

In **Scenario 1**, the information is already known, and the customer is asking for sharing that information.
In **Scenario 2**, the information is not yet known, and the customer is asking to be informed as soon as it becomes known.

---

It is not meaningful to say "We will let you know when this option be available" which mixes up the tenses.

Comment: I like your two scenarios - they are good. But.... your explanation is wrong. In **Scenario 1** the information is not yet known (by the Agent), and the Agent is saying "we will let you know the information when we have the information"; but (and this is key) when the information is given, it will be information on a future event. In **Scenario 2** when the information is given, the event will be in the present.

Comment: I made it a 3-person story because the question mentioned "we", but the situation remains same even if we had only "Customer" and "Agent", in which case "Agent" already knows about the availability, but he takes a few seconds to recollect and respond.

Comment: After some thinking, I feel the best way to highlight the Difference is: In Scenario 1, Customer is asking  (Can you tell me . . .) for information (. . . when the option will be available ?) and Agent responds that he will give the information. In Scenario 2, Customer is asking Agent to do something (Can you tell me . . .) when some condition is met (. . .when the option becomes available ?) and Agent responds that he will do it.

Comment: your comment still does not adequately explain the distinction. In either scenario the phrase "we will let you know" means "we will give you information in the future". The distinction is that in Scenario 1 the information will be "it will be available on this date", in Scenario 2 the information will be "it is available now".

Comment: Yes, I agree with that, but it must be coupled with what is requested. Scenario 1 is "Can you tell me now?", while Scenario 2 is "Can you do this for me when [some condition is true] ?"

Comment: I found the Scenario 1 example compelling enough. But then re-read it, the sentence isn't working as it appears to be on first read. The agent is actually repeating the same words out of customer's mouth when they're saying 'when this option will be available.' It's not a case of a sentence with 2 clauses, a main and subordinating clause as it appears. I think one will notice if they're being meticulous. My conclusion is that such structures are only to be found where the speaker is answering by employing the interrogative sentence, which was used to inquire of them, as a declarative <cont.>

Comment: sentence. In short the structure is like - ''we'll let you know" followed by "whatever they were asked," here using the same wording, almost out of the inquirer's mouth. This isn't a case of a standalone sentence, because if it were to be, the sentence would seem to have been constructed in a bad-style. Scenario 2 could be said to be a stand-alone sentence, because it makes perfect sense even if there is no context available to it or let's say as per the grammar rules regarding the clauses, the scenario 2 would qualify as acceptable.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that, but it must be coupled with what is requested. Scenario 1 is "Can you tell me [information X] now ?", while Scenario 2 is "Can you do this [tell me or wake me or . . .] when [some condition is true] in the future ?". Response for 1 is "Sure, I will tell you now" & Response for 2 is "Sure I will do that for you later". Distinction made by you is also very relevant. {{{{I am not able to edit my previous comment}}}}

Comment: @Semyonov, I used a fictitious dialogue, which sounds unnatural with Agent repeating the words of Customer. That was only for high-lighting the reason for the response. For Scenario 1, Customer could well have said "I want to buy Option A", and Agent would have responded with "That option is not available now. I will let you know when that option will be available.[few seconds delay to check his references] That option will be available from Friday".

Comment: @Prem The agent's response seems to suggest they're asked about the future availability of the option. You're certainly assuming that to be the customer's inquiry in your eg. and using it as it would be phrased in a question. Eg. May I know 'when this option will be available'? Yes I'll let you know 'when this option will be available'. I don't know if there's any term for it, but it's surely ready-made borrowing the phrase from an interrogative to make a declarative sentence.

Comment: The two different answers could be given to the same initial question. Customer: "I really like Option A; can I have it please?". Agent option 1: "I'm really sorry, that's not available yet, and I don't have information on availability to hand. When I'm back in the office tomorrow, I will let you know when it will be available." Agent option 2: "I'm sorry, that's not available yet. I'll let you know when it's available." The distinction is not the question asked, the distinction is whether the Agent will know availability in advance of it actually being available.

Comment: @AndyT I would disagree, I think you're still missing the point, the issue we're debating is if the Option 1 with repetitive 'will' auxiliary is valid?  I think the answer would be YES, GIVEN the subordinating-clause, brought directly from the question, as illustrated in my previous post, is merely appended to the main clause. However, the sentence would sound absolute non-sense to me if used as a standalone sentence, with no context. "I'll fetch some flowers for you, when I'll go to the market," some might like to add a prepositional phrase after market, but it would still be incorrect.<con.>

Comment: The correct way to say this would be - "I'll fetch some flowers for you, when I go to the market." It may be today, tomorrow, next week, month and so on. Justifying the use of future tense in the subordinating clause by signifying the speaker's conviction about the definite occurrence of a future event is erroneous indeed. Conclusion - The former sentence gives the look of an absolute sentence, but it's not if we have no context available to it. The latter, is the correct way of forming future-tense sentences with main and subordinating clause.

Comment: A good guideline here for starters and those in confusion about the correct usage - http://www.englishgrammar.org/tenses-subordinate-clauses/

Comment: @AndySemyonov - Having context or not does not change whether the sentence is a valid construction or not! Can Option 1 be a valid sentence - Yes. Does it mean what the OP meant it to mean - unlikely, but we cannot say for sure. And hence an answer should cover both meanings.

Comment: @AndySemyonov - I completely disagree with your sentence that *"Justifying the use of future tense in the subordinating clause by signifying the speaker's conviction about the definite occurrence of a future event is erroneous indeed."* It is not erroneous unless we know for sure that the speaker did not intend it!

Comment: @AndyT Have you yet opened the link that I posted? Debate with me after you've gone through it thoroughly.

Comment: @AndySemyonov - Yes, I opened your link. What is your point?

Comment: @AndyT Well great on you to have visited the website, now what did you get to learn there?

Comment: @AndySemyonov - Nothing. Because I already knew it. And that doesn't invalidate what I've said.

Comment: @AndyT Very well, to persist to debate with you would make me guilty of ploughing the seashore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22517/discussion-between-andyt-and-andy-semyonov).